# Issue in retrieving the date field from the DB2 query in vbscript

Tags: sql, date, vbscript, db2

Whenever the table has Date column which has the default value as 0001-01-01, I am getting the below error.  Please help me to correct this problem.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 13:09:51 UTC

Message: Invalid procedure call or argument: 'showList.fields(...).Value'
Line: 139
Char: 7
Code: 0

```
dim fso,conn

sqlStr = "select * from "& tablename & " "& whereclause & ""

Set oFTPScriptFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFTPScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sFTPTemp = oFTPScriptShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
fpath1= sFTPTemp & tablename &".csv"

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
Conn.ConnectionTimeout = 60
Conn.CommandTimeout = 60

Conn.open "Provider=IBMDADB2;Hostname=1.1.1.1;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=50000;Database=" & dbalias &      ";Uid=" & Userid & " ;Pwd= "&  Pwd & ";"
dim a, showList, intcount
set a = fso.createtextfile(fPath1)
set showList = conn.execute(sqlStr)

if showlist.eof  then
   a.write "No Rows found"
else
   for intcount = 0 to showList.fields.count -1
   if intcount <> showList.fields.count-1 then
      a.write """" & showList.fields(intcount).name & ""","
   else
      a.write """" & showList.fields(intcount).name & """"
   end if
   next
   a.writeline ""
   do while not showList.eof
   for intcount = 0 to showList.fields.count - 1
   if intcount <> showList.fields.count - 1 then
      a.write """" & showList.fields(intcount).value & ""","
   else
      a.write """" & showList.fields(intcount).value & """"
   end if
   next
   a.writeline ""
   showList.movenext
  loop
end if
showList.close
set showList = nothing
set a = nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48y0723t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), your 'default date' is out of range:

> In Microsoft Windows, the range of valid dates is January 1, 100 A.D.
>   through December 31, 9999 A.D.; the ranges vary among operating
>   systems.

A simple test:

```
>> WScript.Echo DateAdd("yyyy", -1900, Date)
>>
31.03.114
>> WScript.Echo DateAdd("yyyy", -2000, Date)
>>
Error Number:       5
Error Description:  Invalid procedure call or argument
```

supports the assumption that VBScript chokes when trying to convert the database value to a VBScript Date.

As I doubt that your real world problem involves dates like 0001-01-01, the correct remedy would be to store NULL in your table(s) for unknown dates and - perhaps - set the default to something that makes sense in your specific domain *and* fall in VBScript's date range.

If you have to deal with the problem in your script, your options are

- use the queries to get an additional flag for out-of-range dates and look at this before you try to access the date value
- change the queries to get the date value stringified, write a 'accessTheDates' function that looks at the string value and returns a valid date or Null/a valid special date
- isolate the date access in a small function with a *local* On Error Resume Next that returns a valid date or - in case of error - Null/a valid special date